# Write a for loop to remove punctuation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been tasked with writing a for loop to remove some punctuation in a list of strings, storing the answers in a new list. I know how to do this with one string, but not in a loop.

For example: `phrases = ['hi there!', 'thanks!']` etc.

```
import string
new_phrases = []
for i in phrases:
    if i not in string.punctuation
```

Then I get a bit stuck at this point. Do I append? I've tried `yield` and `return`, but realised that's for functions.

Comment: write your expected output

Comment: Your `for` isn't doing anything becuase if statement isn't indented (so if is outside for scope)

Comment: You can either update your current list or append the new value in another list. the update will be better because it takes constant space while append takes O(n) space.

Answer (score 2):

You can either update your current list or append the new value in another list. the update will be better because it takes constant space while append takes O(n) space.

```
phrases = ['hi there!', 'thanks!']
i = 0
for el in phrases:
    new_el = el.replace("!", "")
    phrases[i] = new_el
    i += 1
print (phrases)
```

will give output: ['hi there', 'thanks']

Comment: The question asked to return the result in a new list.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
import re
new_phrases = []

for word in phrases:
    new_phrases.append(re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','', word))
```

This uses the regex library to turn all punctuation into a 'blank' string. Essentially, removing it

Answer (score 1):

If phrases contains any punctuation then replace it with "" and append to the new_phrases

```
import string
new_phrases = []
phrases = ['hi there!', 'thanks!']
for i in phrases:
    for pun in string.punctuation:
        if pun in i:
            i = i.replace(pun,"")
    new_phrases.append(i)
print(new_phrases)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['hi there', 'thanks']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` module and `list comprehension` to do it in single line:

```
phrases = ['hi there!', 'thanks!']

import string
import re

new_phrases = [re.sub('[{}]'.format(string.punctuation), '', i) for i in phrases]
new_phrases
#['hi there', 'thanks']
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your *forma mentis*, I'll do like this:

```
for word in phrases: #for each word
    for punct in string.punctuation: #for each punctuation
        w=w.replace(punct,'') # replace the punctuation character with nothing (remove punctuation)
    new_phrases.append(w) #add new "punctuationless text" to your output
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using the powerful `translate()` method on each string of your input list, which seems really appropriate. It gives the following code, iterating over the input list throug a list comprehension, which is short and easily readable:

```
import string

phrases = ['hi there!', 'thanks!']
translationRule = str.maketrans({k:"" for k in string.punctuation})
new_phrases = [phrase.translate(translationRule) for phrase in phrases]

print(new_phrases)
# ['hi there', 'thanks']
```

Answer (score 0):

Or to only allow spaces and letters:

```
phrases=[''.join(x for x in i if x.isalpha() or x==' ') for i in phrases]
```

Now:

```
print(phrases)
```

Is:

```
['hi there', 'thanks']
```

Answer (score -2):

you should use list comprehension

```
new_list = [process(string) for string in phrases]
```

Comment: This comment has nothing to do with the question

Comment: the asker clearly stated that he knows how to do it for one string. I intended to give direction instead of solving the homework. But haters gonna hate  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯